# How do I get a list of Neo4j nodes in a directed graph starting from a subnode?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a very large graph that has one root node that fans out into multiple nodes. I need to get a list of ALL of the nodes in the subgraph. Other than label, they don't have a common attribute. They are only connected by the "connections"

[image]

Looking at my very simplified graph, I wanted to start from B

MATCH (n: {label:'B'}) and get a list of all the subnodes [E,C,H,F]

or Start with D and get [G] or
start with C and get [H,F]

I though this would get me where I needed to go

```
https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-querying/expand-subgraph/
```

But i can't get the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get all the nodes in the `B` subtree (including the `B` node).

```
MATCH p=(:Foo {label: 'B'})-[*0..]->(n)
RETURN n
```

*Warning: [Variable length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) without a reasonable upper bound can run for a very long time and/or run out of memory.*

Comment: I did try that match p=(:ProgNode {Label:'nonCompliantCwe1045()'})-[*0..]->(n) RETURN n, but it only came back with the root. Yet when I do it in the browser, it has lots of connections.

Comment: Never mind. My error. The final -> needed to be - and it worked as expected. Thank you

Comment: What if I don't want 'B' in the list ?

Comment: You can omit `0..`